# Handwritten lexer

Tags: performance, c, language-design

I'm in the process of designing my own programming language and I have absolutely no experience in computer science other than the code I look at.

I created my first lexer, I've improved it enough that the lexer can actually lex its own source code.

What I'm asking here is how can I improve this lexer?

[GitHub](https://github.com/assyrianic/Handwritten-C-Lexer/tree/master/src)

```
#ifndef __LEX_H__
    #define __LEX_H__


#define is_alphabetic(c) (\
        ((c) >= 'a' && (c) <= 'z')\
        || ((c) >= 'A' && (c) <= 'Z')\
        || (c) == '_'\
        || ((c) < 0))   // lazy unicode support

#define is_potential_identifier(c) (\
        ((c) >= 'a' && (c) <= 'z')\
        || ((c) >= 'A' && (c) <= 'Z')\
        || ((c) >= '0' && (c) <= '9')\
        || (c) == '_'\
        || ((c) < 0))


#define is_space(c) ( (c) == ' ' || (c) == '\t' || (c) == '\r' || (c) == '\n' || (c) == '\v' || (c) == '\f' )

#define is_numeric(c)   ( (c) >= '0' && (c) <= '9' )
#define is_hex(c)   ( ((c) >= 'a' && (c) <= 'f') || ((c) >= 'A' && (c) <= 'F') )

#define is_numeral(c)   (is_numeric((c)) || is_hex((c)))


/* tokens enum */
enum n_token {
    Invalid     =   0,
    Equal,          // =
    EqualCmp,       // ==
    Semicolon,      // ;
    Plus,           // +
    PlusEqual,      // +=
    Increment,      // ++
    Dash,           // -
    MinusEqual,     // -=
    Decrement,      // --
    Asterisk,       // *
    MultEqual,      // *=
    DivSlash,       // /
    DivEqual,       // /=
    LeftParens,     // (
    RiteParens,     // )
    NumIdent,       // vsnjdfn
    NumConstant,        // 548348
    NumConstantHex,     // 0x4E24FDA
    LeftSqBracket,      // [
    RightSqBracket,     // ]
    LeftCurlBrace,      // {
    RightCurlBrace,     // }
    Dot,            // .
    Colon,          // :
    Comma,          // ,
    LeftArrow,      // <
    LeftBitShift,       // <<
    LeftBitShiftEqual,  // <<=
    LessEqual,      // <=
    RightArrow,     // >
    RightBitShift,      // >>
    RightBitShiftEqual, // >>=
    GreaterEqual,       // >=
    NumConstantReal,    // 453.54354
    QuestionMark,       // ?
    HashSym,        // #
    Ampersand,      // &
    AndEqual,       // &=
    BoolAnd,        // &&
    Carot,          // ^
    XorEqual,       // ^=
    Percent,        // %
    ModuloEqual,        // %=
    ExclamationMark,    // !
    NotEqual,       // !=
    VerticalBar,        // |
    OrEqual,        // |=
    BoolOr,         // ||
    Tilde,          // ~
    StringConstant,     // "352dfsgnj34"
    CharConstant,       // 's'
    LeftSlash,      // '\\'
    Keyword,        // struct
    AtSign,         // @
    Ellipses,       // ...
    Arrow,          // ->
    NumConstantHexFloat,    // 0x0.3p10
    DollarSign,     // $
};

struct s_token {
    char        word[512];
    enum n_token    toktype;
};

struct lexer {
    unsigned int count, size;
    struct s_token *array;
};

void tokenize_string(char*, struct lexer*);
void print_tokens_colored(struct lexer*);

#endif
```

lex.c

```
#include "lex.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


static int is_array_full(struct lexer *vec)
{
    return (vec->count >= vec->size);
}

static void resize_array(struct lexer *vec)
{
    vec->size <<= 1;
    vec->array = realloc(vec->array, sizeof(struct s_token) * vec->size);
}
static void add_to_array(struct lexer *vec, enum n_token tok, char *codestring, unsigned int size)
{
    if (is_array_full(vec))
        resize_array(vec);

    vec->array[vec->count].toktype = tok;
    strncpy( vec->array[vec->count].word, codestring, size );
    vec->count++;
}

/*
lol here some code
*/

#define reset_string(str)   memset(wording, '\0', sizeof((str)));\
                    i=0;

#define PrintIter       printf("*iter => %c\n", *iter);
#define KEYWORDS        34

void tokenize_string(char *code, struct lexer *vec)
{
    char *iter = code;
    char wording[512] = "";
    unsigned int i = 0;

    const char *keywords[KEYWORDS] = {
        "auto", "const", "double", "float", "int", "short", "struct", "unsigned",
        "break", "continue", "else", "for", "long", "signed", "switch", "void",
        "case", "default", "enum", "goto", "register", "sizeof", "typedef", "volatile",
        "char", "do", "extern", "if", "return", "static", "union", "while", "inline", "alignof"
    };

    while ( *iter != '\0' ) {
        while ( is_space(*iter) && *iter != '\0' )
            ++iter;

        if (*iter == '/' && iter[1] == '*') {       // found C style /**/ comment
            do {
                ++iter;
            }
            while ( !(*iter == '*' && iter[1] == '/') );
            iter += 2;
        }

        if (*iter == '/' && iter[1] == '/') {       // found C++ style // comment
            while ( *iter != '\n' )
                ++iter;
        }
        if (*iter == '\\' && iter[1] == '\n') {     // formatting Left slash check
            add_to_array(vec, LeftSlash, "\\", 2);
            iter += 2;
        }

        if (*iter == '\"') {    // found string literal, adjust for "\\" so we won't crash
            wording[i++] = *iter++;
            while ( *iter != '\"' ) {
                if (*iter == '\\' && iter[1] == '\"' && iter[-1] != '\\') {
                    wording[i++] = *iter++;
                }
                wording[i++] = *iter++;
            }
            wording[i++] = *iter++;
        }
        if (wording[0] != '\0') {
            //printf("wording => %s\n\n", wording);
            add_to_array(vec, StringConstant, wording, i+1);
            reset_string(wording);
        }

        if ( *iter == '\'' ) {  // found character literal, adjust for '\\' so we won't crash
            wording[i++] = *iter++;
            int counter=0;
            while (*iter != '\'' && counter < 2) {
                if (*iter == '\\' && iter[1] == '\'' && iter[-1] != '\\') {
                    wording[i++] = *iter++;
                }
                wording[i++] = *iter++;
                ++counter;
            }
            wording[i++] = *iter++;
        }
        if (wording[0] != '\0') {
            add_to_array(vec, CharConstant, wording, i+1);
            reset_string(wording);
        }

        if (*iter == '0' && (iter[1] == 'x' || iter[1] == 'X')) {   // found hexadecimal constant
            wording[i++] = *iter++; // copy both 0 and x
            wording[i++] = *iter++;

            while ( is_numeral(*iter) ) {
                wording[i++] = *iter++;
            }
            if ( *iter == '.' && is_numeral(iter[1]) ) {    // found hexadecimal float
                wording[i++] = *iter++;
                while ( is_numeral(*iter) )
                    wording[i++] = *iter++;
                if (*iter == 'p' && is_numeral(iter[1])) {  // stuff like 0x0.3p10.
                    wording[i++] = *iter++;
                    while ( is_numeral(*iter) )
                        wording[i++] = *iter++;
                }
                if (wording[0] != '\0') {
                    add_to_array(vec, NumConstantHexFloat, wording, i+1);
                    reset_string(wording);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (wording[0] != '\0') {
                    add_to_array(vec, NumConstantHex, wording, i+1);
                    reset_string(wording);
                }
            }
        }

        while ( is_numeric(*iter) ) {   // found decimal constant
            wording[i++] = *iter++;
        }
        if ( *iter == '.' && is_numeric(iter[1]) ) {    // found floating point number
            wording[i++] = *iter++;
            while ( is_numeric(*iter) )
                wording[i++] = *iter++;

            if ( (*iter == 'p' || *iter == 'P' || *iter == 'e' || *iter == 'E') && is_numeric(iter[1]) )
            {
                wording[i++] = *iter++;
                while ( is_numeric(*iter) )
                    wording[i++] = *iter++;
            }
            if (*iter == 'f')   // stuff like 2.0f etc.
                wording[i++] = *iter++;

            if (wording[0] != '\0') {
                add_to_array(vec, NumConstantReal, wording, i+1);
                reset_string(wording);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (wording[0] != '\0') {
                add_to_array(vec, NumConstant, wording, i+1);
                reset_string(wording);
            }
        }

        if (is_alphabetic(*iter)) { // found an identifier or potential keyword
            while (is_potential_identifier(*iter))
                wording[i++] = *iter++;
        }
        if (wording[0] != '\0') {
            int x;
            int found_keyword = 0;
            for ( x=0 ; x<KEYWORDS ; ++x ) {
                if ( !strcmp(wording, keywords[x]) ) {
                    found_keyword = 1;
                }
            }
            if (found_keyword)
                add_to_array(vec, Keyword, wording, i+1);
            else add_to_array(vec, NumIdent, wording, i+1);
            reset_string(wording);
        }

        switch ( *iter ) {
            case '=':
                if (iter[1] == '=') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, EqualCmp, "==", 3);
                }   
                else add_to_array(vec, Equal, "=", 2);
                break;
            case ';':
                add_to_array(vec, Semicolon, ";", 2);
                break;
            case ':':
                add_to_array(vec, Colon, ":", 2);
                break;
            case '+':   // possible uses => left unary is positive, twice unary is increment, once binary is addition
                if (iter[1] == '=') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, PlusEqual, "+=", 3);
                }
                else if (iter[1] == '+') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, Increment, "++", 3);
                }
                else add_to_array(vec, Plus, "+", 2);
                break;
            case '-':   // possible uses => left unary is negating, twice unary is decrement, one binary is minus
                if (iter[1] == '=') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, MinusEqual, "-=", 3);
                }
                else if (iter[1] == '-') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, Decrement, "--", 3);
                }
                else if (iter[1] == '>') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, Arrow, "->", 3);
                }
                else add_to_array(vec, Dash, "-", 2);
                break;
            case '*':   // leftward unary is dereferencing ptr, binary be mult. Also check for / as ending comment
                if (iter[1] == '=') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, MultEqual, "*=", 3);
                }
                else add_to_array(vec, Asterisk, "*", 2);
                break;
            case '/':   // check for * and / as comment EDIT: DONE
                if (iter[1] == '=') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, DivEqual, "/=", 3);
                }
                else add_to_array(vec, DivSlash, "/", 2);
                break;
            case '(':
                add_to_array(vec, LeftParens, "(", 2);
                break;
            case ')':
                add_to_array(vec, RiteParens, ")", 2);
                break;
            case '[':
                add_to_array(vec, LeftSqBracket, "[", 2);
                break;
            case ']':
                add_to_array(vec, RightSqBracket, "]", 2);
                break;
            case '{':
                add_to_array(vec, LeftCurlBrace, "{", 2);
                break;
            case '}':
                add_to_array(vec, RightCurlBrace, "}", 2);
                break;
            case '.':
                if (iter[1] == '.' && iter[2] == '.') {
                    iter += 2;
                    add_to_array(vec, Ellipses, "...", 4);
                }
                else add_to_array(vec, Dot, ".", 2);
                break;
            case ',':
                add_to_array(vec, Comma, ",", 2);
                break;
            case '<':
                if (iter[1] == '<') {
                    if (iter[2] == '=') {
                        add_to_array(vec, LeftBitShiftEqual, "<<=", 4);
                        iter += 2;
                    }
                    else {
                        add_to_array(vec, LeftBitShift, "<<", 3);
                        ++iter;
                    }
                }
                else if (iter[1] == '=') {
                    add_to_array(vec, LessEqual, "<=", 3);
                    ++iter;
                }
                else add_to_array(vec, LeftArrow, "<", 2);
                break;
            case '>':
                if (iter[1] == '>') {
                    if (iter[2] == '=') {
                        add_to_array(vec, RightBitShiftEqual, ">>=", 4);
                        iter += 2;
                    }
                    else {
                        add_to_array(vec, RightBitShift, ">>", 3);
                        ++iter;
                    }
                }
                else if (iter[1] == '=') {
                    add_to_array(vec, GreaterEqual, ">=", 3);
                    ++iter;
                }
                else add_to_array(vec, RightArrow, ">", 2);
                break;
            case '?':
                add_to_array(vec, QuestionMark, "?", 2);
                break;
            case '#':
                add_to_array(vec, HashSym, "#", 2);
                break;
            case '&':
                if (iter[1] == '=') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, AndEqual, "&=", 3);
                }
                else if (iter[1] == '&') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, BoolAnd, "&&", 3);
                }
                else add_to_array(vec, Ampersand, "&", 2);
                break;
            case '^':
                if (iter[1] == '=') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, XorEqual, "^=", 3);
                }
                else add_to_array(vec, Carot, "^", 2);
                break;
            case '%':
                if (iter[1] == '=') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, ModuloEqual, "%=", 3);
                }
                else add_to_array(vec, Percent, "%", 2);
                break;
            case '!':
                if (iter[1] == '=') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, NotEqual, "!=", 3);
                }
                else add_to_array(vec, ExclamationMark, "!", 2);
                break;
            case '|':
                if (iter[1] == '=') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, OrEqual, "|=", 3);
                }
                else if (iter[1] == '|') {
                    ++iter;
                    add_to_array(vec, BoolOr, "||", 3);
                }
                else add_to_array(vec, VerticalBar, "|", 2);
                break;
            case '~':
                add_to_array(vec, Tilde, "~", 2);
                break;
            case '@':
                add_to_array(vec, AtSign, "@", 2);
                break;
        }
        ++iter;
    }
}

void print_tokens_colored(struct lexer *vec)
{
#define KNRM    "\x1B[0m"   // Normal
#define KRED    "\x1B[31m"
#define KGRN    "\x1B[32m"
#define KYEL    "\x1B[33m"
#define KBLU    "\x1B[34m"
#define KMAG    "\x1B[35m"
#define KCYN    "\x1B[36m"
#define KWHT    "\x1B[37m"
#define RESET   "\033[0m"   // Reset obviously

    int i;
    for (i=0 ; i<vec->count ; ++i) {
        switch (vec->array[i].toktype) {
            case NumConstantHex:
            case NumConstant:
            case StringConstant:
            case CharConstant:
            case NumConstantReal:
                printf("token #%i => %s%s%s\n", i, KMAG, vec->array[i].word, RESET);
                break;
            case NumIdent:
                printf("token #%i => %s%s%s\n", i, KCYN, vec->array[i].word, RESET);
                break;
            case Keyword:
                printf("token #%i => %s%s%s\n", i, KRED, vec->array[i].word, RESET);
                break;
            default:
                printf("token #%i => %s%s%s\n", i, KGRN, vec->array[i].word, RESET);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to see the definition of `struct lexer` and `enum n_token`?

Comment: it's in the github link

Comment: Please post it here if you want anyone to be able to critique your code.

Comment: the github link is IN the post...

Comment: the github is between the source code panel and my last sentence...

Comment: But sadly the code is not. If you want a critique post it *here*. Otherwise, I'll just move on to another question.

Comment: there, lex.h is added...

Comment: Thank you! This will make it easier in some Lovecraftian future where Sourceforge buys GitHub and users start removing their projects, or whatever.

Comment: Not voting, not accepting any answers... don't you like them? Weren't they helpful?

Comment: Please don't write your own lexer. There are so many easy tools that will do this job for you. That are easier to verify, easier to maintain and probably much more efficient.

Comment: i learn by example, not by tool...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `sizeof` with the referenced object rather than `sizeof` referenced type.  With OP code, to determine if the right cast used in a function in `lex.c`, a reviewer is obliged to cross check with code in another file `lex.h`. By using the referenced object, code is more likely to be coded correct initially, easier to review and simpler to update.

   ```
   //                                Is this the right type/size?
   // vec->array = realloc(vec->array, sizeof(struct s_token)    * vec->size);

   //                               Certainly the right size          
   vec->array = realloc(vec->array, sizeof *(vec->array)     * vec->size);
   ```
2. Filling a large (512) array with zeros adds little value.  A simple `strcpy()` will suffice.  If code is concerned about overrun, add a test.

   ```
   // strncpy( vec->array[vec->count].word, codestring, size );
   assert(strlen(codestring) < sizeof vec->array[vec->count].word); 
   strcpy( vec->array[vec->count].word, codestring);
   ```
3. The above simplifies calls.

   ```
   // add_to_array(vec, Ellipses, "...", 4);
   add_to_array(vec, Ellipses, "...");
   ```
4. Avoid magic numbers.  The `512` is `char wording[512]` is certainly derived from the 512 in `char word[512];`  Use a macro to define both `#define LEXER_N 512` or *derive* it.

   ```
   void tokenize_string(char *code, struct lexer *vec) {
     ...
     // char wording[512] = "";
     char wording[sizeof vec->array_>word] = "";
   ```
5. Assigning an entire array to zeros is not needed - albeit useful to debug buggy code.  For *strings*, simply assigning the first to 0 is sufficient.

   ```
   // char wording[512] = "";
   char wording[512];
   wording[0] = '\0';
   ```
6. Note that `is_hex()` differs in functionality from the standard C function `isxdigit()` which returns non-zero (truth) on `isxdigit('4')`.  Suggest:

   ```
   // #define is_hex(c)   ( ((c) >= 'a' && (c) <= 'f') ...
   #define is_hex(c)   (is_numeric(c) || ((c) >= 'a' && (c) <= 'f') ...
   ```
7. Someplace is other code, the range of `enum n_token` will be assessed.  Consider:

   ```
   enum n_token {
       Invalid     =   0,
       Equal,          // =
       EqualCmp,       // ==
       ....
       NumConstantHexFloat, // 0x0.3p10
       DollarSign,          // $
       n_token_N                            // add
   };

   if (token < 0 || token >= n_token_N) Handle_Code_Error();
   ```
8. No need for `KEYWORDS` or magic number `34`

   ```
     // const char *keywords[KEYWORDS] = {
     const char *keywords[] = {
       "auto", "const", "double", "float", "int", "short", "struct", the rest };

     // for ( x=0 ; x<KEYWORDS ; ++x )
     for ( x=0 ; x<sizeof keywords/sizeof keywords[0] ; ++x )
   ```
9. I'd expect `switch ( *iter ) {` to have a `default:` case to catch malformed text.
10. Minor: Simplify if `is_space('\0')` is certainly false.

    ```
    // while ( is_space(*iter) && *iter != '\0' )
    while (is_space(*iter))
    ```
11. Minor. As `enum n_token` is along list, alphabetize it - easier on debug/maintenance.

    ```
    Ampersand,      // &
    AndEqual,       // &=
    Arrow,          // ->
    AtSign,         // @
    ```
12. Questionable code.  [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) values are all positive [0-0x10FFFF].

    ```
    // ????             
    | ((c) < 0))   // lazy unicode support
    ```
13. Code lacks check for buffer over run.

    ```
    assert(i +1 < sizeof wording);
    wording[i++] = ...
    ```

Answer (score 4):

This is a fairly straightforward way to write a lexer, and as such is really easy to read. Nice work! Here are my thoughts on how it could be improved:

## Don't Reinvent the Wheel

In general, it's best not to write your own lexer unless you have a very simple domain-specific language. It's a good exercise, but in the real world, you should use a tool like [lex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29). The input files are significantly smaller and easier to understand, and less likely to contain bugs. But I assume you're doing it to teach yourself about the process, which is a great idea!

## Avoid macros

You use a lot of macros. There are 2 problems with this:

1. [Macros are dangerous](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/12/17/macros-why-theyre-evil/) - If someone calls one of these macros thinking it's a function, and they do a pre or post increment, for example, very weird things will happen and it will be very difficult to debug.
2. Many of your macros mimic standard library functions, which is confusing. Just use the standard functions, and if you need additional functionality, write an inline or static wrapper function.

## Long Functions Are Hard To Understand

In general, really long functions, and in particular really long loops, can be hard to understand. It takes significantly more effort to keep all the moving pieces in one's mind while reading the code. I recommend breaking up `tokenize_string()` into dozens of smaller functions. For example, I might change the `while` loop to look something like this:

```
while ( *iter != '\0' ) {
    trim_leading_whitespace(&iter);
    remove_C_comments(&iter);
    remove_Cpp_comments(&iter);
    handle_newline(&iter, vec);
    //... etc.
```

This makes the intent of the code clearer and easier to follow. Chances are, those short function will get inlined automatically and it will be just as fast as it is now.

## Handle Issues When They Occur

In `add_to_array()` you first check to see if the array is full and if so resize it. Then you do some things which may fill up the array. This seems backwards to me. I'd put the check and resize immediately after incrementing `vec->count`. It's true that you may end up allocating extra memory you don't need on very rare occasions where you have allocated exactly as much memory as you need up-front, but this situation is rare and unlikely to be problematic.

## Handle Errors

What is problematic is that you don't handle the potential error from `realloc()`. If it can't allocate more memory, it will return `NULL` and `vec->array` will be invalid. (Some sources are saying it will remain pointing to the old location - that's also a problem as you didn't allocate any more memory, but `vec->size` says its larger. Either way, it's a problem.) In addition, there isn't a single call to `free()` anywhere in your code. You're going to be leaking a lot of memory!

## Why Have Arbitrary Limits?

I notice that the `s_token.word` member is limited to 512 bytes. Why limit it? And if you are going to limit it, why is the limit 512? If there's some significance to 512, give it a named constant, as you've done with `KEYWORDS` for example.

## Use `const` Where Appropriate

Speaking of constants, you should mark function arguments as `const` if they aren't going to be changed by the function. For example, in `add_to_array()`, the token is copied and the string is also copied. That means that the originals are not changed, so you should mark `tok`, `codestring` and `size` as `const`. It tells both the compiler and the reader that they don't need to worry about those values changing in that function.

## Use The Appropriate `#define`s

I notice that you're defining `KNRM`, `KRED`, etc. Shouldn't those be defined by some standard header? If not, the names could be a little clearer, or there could at least be a comment explaining what they are.